# Ruby undefined method each

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

i am new to ruby language and i tried to learn it now.
i have a class`Company` with method `find_applicants`

```
class Company
attr_accessor :jobs
## TODO: This method should update the `jobs` property to an array of instances of
## class `Job`
def initialize(jobs)
  # Load the json file and loop over the jobs to create an array of instance of `Job`
  # Assign the `jobs` instance variable.
@jobs = jobs
end

## TODO: Impelement this method to return applicants from all jobs with a
## tag matching this keyword
def find_applicants(keyword)
# Use the `jobs` instance variable.
applicants = []
 @jobs.each do |job|
  job.applicants.each do |applicant|
    applicant.tags.each do |tag|
      if keyword.eql? tag
         # ...
      end
    end
  end
end 

end
```

and the main.rb

```
require './src/company.rb'
require './src/applicant.rb'
require './src/job.rb'
require 'json'



company = Company.new('data/boundless.json')

applicants = company.find_applicants('google')
puts applicants
```

and when compile this i have this error

> /Users/user/Desktop/BoundlessCaseStudy/src/company.rb:34:in `find_applicants': undefined method`each' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
>       from main.rb:11:in `'

please help

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are passing the name of the json file where the jobs are, instead an array of jobs

```
company = Company.new('data/boundless.json')
```

but you did no wrote que code that parse this file, as the comment correctly says you should

```
# Load the json file and loop over the jobs to create an array of instance of `Job`,
```

So the variable @jobs is receiving a string, and you will get this error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for "data/boundless.json":String
```

write the code to parse the file and set the @jobs variable correctly